# How can I use "partial pooling" to shrink cells with a small sample size towards the mean in a contingency table?

Tags: survey, multilevel-analysis, contingency-tables, proportion, regularization

How can I use "partial pooling" to shrink cells with a small sample size towards the mean in a contingency table? I am interested in the proportions within each cell with a positive response.

To clarify, I am tabulating various customer demographics survey across a range of stores. I would consider a standard contingency table with no shrinkage a "no pooling" estimate, and a mean proportion for all stores a "total pooling" estimate. I am interested in a compromise between the two, with stores with a small sample size having their variance and point estimates shrunk towards the total pooling estimate.

This picture is further complicated because the proportions are typically quite low, with a total pooling estimate of 0.5%.

What is the recommended way to construct such a contingency table? Should I use a hierarchical model with only a store level variables? And, if so, what sort of GLM should I use?

Some synthetic data with similar characteristics to mine is below:

```
set.seed <- 2012

gen.prop <- function(n, x)sample(c(rep(T, round(n*x, 0)), rep(F, n - round(n*x, 0))), n)

df <- data.frame(Store=factor(c(rep("a", 1000), rep("b", 3000), rep("c", 1000), 
                                rep("d", 20), rep("e", 10), rep("f", 10))), 
                 Likes.Cats=c(gen.prop(1000, 0.2), gen.prop(3000, 0.006), gen.prop(1000, 0.002),
                              gen.prop(20, 0.4), gen.prop(10, 0.1), gen.prop(10, 0)))

# Total pooling estimate
round(mean(df$Likes.Cats), 3)
    # No pooling estimate
    round(prop.table(table(df$Store,  df$Likes.Cats), 1), 3)
```